# Why does android build fail and show error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build, apk

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwe5f.png)I am new to unity and I have a small problem . I installed the editor from the unity archive due to the buggy hub , but everything worked fine in the editor until the android build. I have completed my game and now I want to test it on a mobile phone . I installed the android build support from the archive but the editor keeps showing the error that JDK and SDK should be installed from the hub , but the add module option is not in the hub. I also read in another forum that changing the text from "false" to "true" in editor file in unity hub's folder fixes the problem but this showed an empty add module option . I cant change the editor as my game uses assets like bolt and post - processing .Please fix this problem .

Comment: You need to delete everything and install Unity HUB.. Its not buggy at all. Let the HUB do everything for you. Just select Android module while choosing different modules in Unity Installation

Answer (score 0):

I am not quiet sure what your problem is with Unity hub and why it is "buggy" for you.

If Unity tells you that JDK and Android SDK should be installed that means that it does not find the necessary platform modules. Makes sure these are linked correctly. you can find them under Edit->Preferences->External Tools
[image: External Tools preferences]
Make sure everything is setup correctly. You can read more about [Android Setup](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/android-sdksetup.html) at Unity documentation

Comment: I think you didn't understand , the hub is buggy in the sense that when I tried to install the editor, installation always failed but that was not the problem because I installed the editor from the unity archive . I know that Unity requires JDK and SDK modules for android build and the module's are installed by the hub . As I download the editor from the archive the add modules option is not present . So I installed the recommended JDK and SDK from the oracle and android website. But after installing the modules unity says , the modules are external and install them from the hub .

Comment: I have also written the same problem in the unity forum website , This might make it clear .

Comment: Link  https://answers.unity.com/questions/1810303/problem-with-android-build-2.html

Comment: but did you link them appropriately then? because from the link you posted the images shows the standard unity path where unity would expect them to be. did you move the JDK and SDK to that path? otherwise you need to adjust the link to the correct path.

Comment: No, I didn't change the path of the JDK and SDK I downloaded them from the archive link --> https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive  (in the release notes , my version 2020.1.12f1) after downloading I installed them but  after installation the spaces for external tools was filled but the highlighted errors were preset.

Comment: yes they are always filled, because that is the standard path unity would expect the tools to be in, but if they are not in that path unity can't link the tools and you will inevitably get the error message you have. That is why i asked if the tools really are in that directory

Comment: I didn't change the location I only installed the Android support in the default location and it also found Unity .

Comment: I also added an image now you will understand.

Comment: the picture you added has nothing to do with your problem. it's not about adding modules in the unity hub, its about the unity version you are running and the path it has set for external tools. if you don't link them correctly (and the sdk is not at the place the linker points to) it will not work, period. And the post on the Unity form only shows that the JDK and SDK are missing and that the easierst way would be to install them via hub, but they can be link correctly without that. anyhow, if you want to do it over the hub reinstall the hub and install the unity version from the hub

Answer (score 0):

I only had to un-check The option of installing JDK and SDK through Unity . Then I could install JDK and SDK externally .